# Can not call a Mysql Stored Procedure more than one time, exists in the same sql file

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My Stored Procedure is

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE Add_Template(
        template_id_             VARCHAR(20),
        file_name_               VARCHAR(100),
        template_description_    VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO application_template_tab VALUES(template_id_,file_name_,template_description_);
END//
```

I call this procedure as follow in the same .sql file

```
call Add_Template('ICT','frmIct.jsp','Information Communication Technology');
call Add_Template('Bac_Bus_Adm','frmBusAdm.jsp','Bachelor of Business Administration');
```

1. Having these procedure callings in a separate file and execute it after executing the stored procedure also works fine.
2. Having only one call after the stored procedure also works fine

But in the same file after the stored procedure, When I add the second call, it gives me the following error,

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'call
>   Add_Template('Bac_Bus_Adm','frmBusAdm.jsp','Bachel' at line 2

**Note:- Table creation Script**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS application_template_tab(
                    app_template_id          VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
                    form_name                VARCHAR(100)   NOT NULL,
                    template_desc            VARCHAR(500)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (app_template_id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file, you are changing the statement delimiter from the default value `;` using `DELIMITER //`.

This is required for complex statements like procedure declarations to be handled correctly by the client.

But the error suggests you are not setting it back to the default.

After `END //` but before the `CALL` statements, you need this:

```
DELIMITER ;  -- note there is a space required before the ;
```